# Why are my variables undefined?

Tags: php, if-statement, math, var, strtotime

To the best of my limited knowledge and abilities with PHP the following code should work:

```
<?php
////DISPLAY DATE OF NEXT COUNCIL MEETING////

$now = date('U'); //get current time
$firstTues = strtotime("-1 month first Tuesday 4pm"); //get first Tuesday of the month
$secondTues = strtotime("-1 month second Tuesday 5pm"); //get second Tuesday of the month
$fourthTues = strtotime("-1 month fourth Tuesday 5pm"); //get forth Tuesday of the month
$nextTues = strtotime("first Tuesday 4pm"); //get first Tuesday of next month

function nextCouncilMeeting() {

//If todays date less than 1st Tuesday at 11pm, display date for 1st Tuesday 4pm.
if ($now < $firstTues) {
    echo date('F j\<\s\u\p\>S\</\s\u\p\> \a\t g:i A', $firstTues);
}

//If todays date greater than 1st Tuesday 5pm and less than 2nd Tuesday 11pm, display date for 2nd Tuesday 5pm
elseif ($now > $firstTues and $now < $secondTues) {
    echo date('F j\<\s\u\p\>S\</\s\u\p\> \a\t g:i A', $secondTues);
}

//If todays date greater than 2nd Tuesday 5pm and less that 4th Tuesday 11pm, display date for 4th Tuesday 5pm
elseif ($now > $secondTues and $now < $fourthTues) {
    echo date('F j\<\s\u\p\>S\</\s\u\p\> \a\t g:i A', $fourthTues);
} 

//If todays date greater than 4th Tuesday
elseif ($now > $fourthTues){
    echo date('F j\<\s\u\p\>S\</\s\u\p\> \a\t g:i A', $nextTues);
}
else{
    echo "foobar";
}
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p id="test">
Current Time: <?php echo date('F j\<\s\u\p\>S\</\s\u\p\> \a\t g:i A',$now); echo " " . $now;?></br>
First Tuesday: <?php echo date('F j\<\s\u\p\>S\</\s\u\p\> \a\t g:i A',$firstTues);echo " " . $firstTues;?></br>
Second Tuesday: <?php echo date('F j\<\s\u\p\>S\</\s\u\p\> \a\t g:i A',$secondTues);echo " " . $secondTues;?></br>
Fourth Tuesday: <?php echo date('F j\<\s\u\p\>S\</\s\u\p\> \a\t g:i A',$fourthTues);echo " " . $fourthTues;?></br>
Next Month First Tuesday: <?php echo date('F j\<\s\u\p\>S\</\s\u\p\> \a\t g:i A',$nextTues);echo " " . $nextTues;?>
</p>
<h2>Next Council Meeting:</h2>
<h1><?php nextCouncilMeeting()?></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

But my variables are throwing an error as undefined, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks @JonathanKuhn, I figured it had to be something dumb, put your comment in an answer and I'll give you some rep. Also, thanks for introducing me to that site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the program with error reporting on and set to show all errors, the issue becomes a little more clear. See [this demo](https://3v4l.org/pkDRc) and the errors it throws. The issue is one of scoping. PHP has functional scope meaning that variables defined outside functions are not visible within functions. You should either pass your value into the function as an argument or go the bad route and declare them as global within your function.